# issue with saving output of show commands to a network device

Tags: python, file-io

I am sending commands to a router via txt file(show 1, show2, show 3). My code prints output to console as expected, however when i try to save it to another txt file it just saves output of "show 3" command

=====================CODE: ================

```py
from netmiko import Netmiko
from getpass import getpass


cisco1 =  {
    "host" :"192.168.100.1",
    "username" : "XXXXX",
    "password": "XXXXX",
    "device_type" : "cisco_ios",
}

net_connect = Netmiko(**cisco1)

print(net_connect.find_prompt())


with open("conf.txt", "r") as f:
    for lines in f:
        lines = f.readline()
        output = net_connect.send_command(lines)

        with open("cmdoutput.txt", "w") as nf:
            nf.write(output)
        print(output)


net_connect.disconnect()
```

Comment: By the way, you can open multiple files on the same code line rather than opening and closing a file for every read line in a file

Comment: @falsetru, as per above query, how to read each command in the file and save to seperate output files.
Example, show running-directory to output1.txt
show system to output2.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Iterating file yield lines. By explicitly calling `readline()`, the code is skiping every other lines.

   ```
   for lines in f:
       lines = f.readline()  # <----
       output = net_connect.send_command(lines)
   ```

   Remove the `readline()` calls.
2. The code is open output file inside loop. It will overwrite existing file. You should open output file once.

---

```
...
with open("conf.txt", "r") as f, open("cmdoutput.txt", "w") as nf:
    for line in f:
        output = net_connect.send_command(line)
        nf.write(output)
        ...
```

BTW, `lines` should be `line`.

Comment: Or open in append mode

Comment: @falsetru: Thank you! for explaining and solving the issue. However i have 2 question: 1) - How for loop is reading file without me giving any read methods (default behavior)? 2) - for line in f:  or for lines in f or for apple in f can we not use anything? why --> lines should be line ?

Comment: @im-c 2. Iterating file yield line by line, not all lines at once.

Comment: @im-c, 1. Because a file object is an iterator. https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator